# Pass row count to a column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table which doesn't have an ID. So I want to add a new column which is 1 to total row number. I opened a new column in the table but I don't know how to fill it with row count. I searched on the Internet but I couldn't find a solution that solves my problem. Can you tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what order do you want to generate this id column? You can use sequence if it just needs to be unique (and not neccessarily gapless). You can also use `row_number` while querying instead of storing the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is

```
update your_table
set id = rownum;
```

However this won't help you with future insertions to this table. If that is something with is going to happen build a sequence.

```
SQL> select max(id) from your_table;

   MAX(ID)
----------


SQL> create sequence your_table_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> update your_table
  2  set id = your_table_seq.nextval;

30 rows updated.

SQL> select max(id) from your_table;

   MAX(ID)
----------
        30

SQL> select id from your_table;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
....
        28
        29
        30

30 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

By the way, now you've added an ID column and populated it be sure to enforce it as a primary key:

```
alter table your_table add constraint your_table_pk primary key (id);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this (works for versions 12c or later):

```
alter table your_table add id number generated always as identity;
```

Though, this also generates new values for column, for future insertions.

Also about `total row number`, this should almost always generate values from 1 to "total row number", but anyway (don't know exactly, when this may work incorrectly), for check this, after `alter` you can do: `select count(*), max(id) from your_table`. values should match together.

Comment: This solution only works for version 12c or later.

Comment: @APC - Thanks, you're correct, updated

Comment: If the OP is using 12c this would be the best solution